# Joining one column from another table and returning empty only the column that doesn't exist

Tags: sql

I have done my search, furthermore I repolished my SQL skills that gained little rust but I still can't get it to work, although I know it is not that complex, This is an SQL/400 program but it has the same queries as SQL.

I have two tables:

**Orders**

```
mainorder   Ordertype             shipper
-----       -----                 -------
1234       priority                 USP
```

**Client**

```
  clientOrder     ClientType          referenceNumber
    -----         -----               ---------------
    1234        individual               REF1234
```

Where `mainorder` and `clientOrder` are the same (just different column name) I am trying to get in one result set the `Orders.shipper` where `Orders.mainorder` = ? and `Orders.Ordertype` =? **AND** a column for `client.referenceNumber` where `client.clientOrder`=? and `client.ClientType`=?

I was able to do this using this query:

```
     select V.*,E.referenceNumber from 
(select H.shipper from Orders H where H.mainorder= '1234' 
     AND H.Ordertype='priority') AS V, 
Client E where E.clientOrder='1234' AND E.ClientType='individual'
```

I also tried bunch of `JOIN` queries but didn't work, they keep giving more information than what I need.

The problem is that `Client.clientOrder` is not guaranteed to be there all the time whenever there is a corresponding `Orders.mainorder`, and when there is no `Client.clientOrder` row corresponding to `Orders.mainorder` the entire resultset will be empty.

What I really want is for the result set to still include information from `Orders` table if there is no corresponding value to `Orders.mainorder` in `Client.clientOrder` so the `referenceNumber` in the result set will simply be an empty column but the other colums will not be empty.

Comment: @Nbk That question is about joining 3 tables. How is it a duplicate for this?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` for this.

Comment: there are only two tables @Barmar hie made a subqiury for the first one that is not necessary

Comment: ```SELECT ... FROM orders LEFT JOIN client ON orders.mainorder = client.clientOrder AND client.clientType = 'individual'```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar left join worked, still had to tweak it bit and use nested select statement to get what I need

Comment: It's unlikely you needed a nested `SELECT` statement @HMA, if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then we can fully answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select
    o.*
    c.referenceNumber
from Orders o
left join Client c 
    on o.mainorder = c.clientOrder
    and c.ClientType = 'individual'
```

If you need a specific Order Number, then just add it to the `WHERE` clause:

```
select
    o.*
    c.referenceNumber
from Orders o
left join Client c 
    on o.mainorder = c.clientOrder
    and c.ClientType = 'individual'
where o.mainorder = 1234 --or '1234' if for some reason your mainorder values are strings and not some numeric type
```

Comment: Had to add nested SELECT statement for me is to be certain that the data I need from  Orders Is included, and only what I need, I tried your approach before I posted this question and it ended up  Not including the information from Orders when there is no matching clientOrder in other table, it also ended up rendering more rows from Orders than what I am asking for, therefore everything I need from Orders was put in nested select, and then I used LEFT join, in the ON condition I only mentioned conditions related to client table: on o.mainorder = c.clientOrder and c.ClientType = 'individual'

Comment: "it ended up Not including the information from Orders when there is no matching clientOrder in other table" - fair point, the expression in the 'WHERE' clause should be in the `LEFT JOIN` to handle that, I'll update my answer.

Comment: "it also ended up rendering more rows from Orders than what I am asking for" - then this is why we really need to see a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with source data and expected results, otherwise we just have to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, I know I am guilty of giving less details then I should, the truth is that I had to construct these non - exiting order- client tables because I could not include actual tables information , the tables I have are much more complex business tables and i just simplfied what i need in two tables I created here

Comment: Yes, that's totally understandable, but people provide MREs all the time with simplified schemas and anonymised/dummy data so that people can help more easily to solve the problem. Otherwise you end up with a [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) situation and we solve the wrong issue for you, or in the wrong way.